# Oracle ORDS update columns

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-ords

when doing an update through ORDS it updates all the columns. not just the columns provided in the json payload. defaulting columns not provided in json to null.

is there a way to only update columns provided in json data?

Comment: Could you provide more insight like what is the endpoint URL you are accessing and tables structure and sample json data. check [here](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/ords/r30/Insert_Update_Delete/Insert_Update_Delete.html) and it should work if you follow the rules

Comment: i don't see how that is relevant.  i have an oracle table with about 20 columns. in my json post data i only provide the columns i want to update but it updates all the columns in the table for that key.  any columns not provided in json are defaulted to null.

Comment: It may sounds irrelevant for you but not for others who need to look into the issue. The case you described is applicable not only to ORDS but any REST API with such scenarios. I may or may not able to help you but to understand the problem minimum examples required. As I provided you the link it clearly does the same what you expect but in your case it is not. Its fine for me in case others understand the issue better and provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior when an object is REST enabled through `ORDS.ENABLE_OBJECT` or by using the **Enable Object** button if you're in APEX. There is no way to change that behavior. If you want different behavior, you will need to build your own module/template/handler with the logic that you want.

Comment: I have not worked with ORDS but what to do you mean by default behavior ? Are you saying it will always update all the columns irrespective of what payload is being set ? Check this [link](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/ords/r30/Insert_Update_Delete/Insert_Update_Delete.html#section4:~:text=Updating%20Data%20Using%20RESTful%20Services) .I see it only updates the columns being sent to the request not all.

Comment: AUTOREST feature for a table the PUT updates all columns by design. That example isn't AUTOREST, it's a service you code yourself, so you can make it work any which way you want.

Comment: As Jeff said, that example is not AutoREST. The example below uses AutoREST and you can see when the PUT operation is called, the rest of the fields are set to null.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-autorest

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, @EJ Egyed  Thanks both for the clarification. I got the by default design which update all the columns but can't we change the behaviour with additional configuration ? Where do you see in my given example it is not `AutoREST` ? Which service code you are talking about ? It does the same with an IDE what we can do with PLSQL calling API in the link given by EJ Egyed.

Comment: I will do my homework anyway. If you have time to clarify my question I will appreciate or else it's fine for the moment.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30, if you look at your link you will see that a module/template/handler is being defined, but those are not used when an object is enabled through `ORDS.ENABLE_OBJECT`. If you look at my link, no module/template/handler is being set up.

Comment: @EJ Egyed, Thank you again and I would say its enough for me at this very point. :)